# How to call function in angular js controller after $location.path

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller which has a method called goToNext(), which should change the 
`

```
 angular.controller('myCtrl',function(){
  function goToNext(){
   $location.path('/abc.html');
   // here I need to run some code based on dom of abc.
  }
 });
```

`
BTW, abc.html should have same controller.

I am novice to angular js so may be I am not able to search with proper terminolgy but believe I have spent full day searching the way.

Any guidance???

Comment: AngularJS is for building single-page-apps, so it won't work as you expect if you try to use multiple pages with it and link to those external pages.  Instead use at looking ngRoute or  ui-router

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a **Single Page Application** framework so it will only work on one page at a time. If you want to do something with `abc.html` you could simply redirect the browser to that page, and that page should contain another Angular app. And after it loads you can do your thing.

You need to have an angular app for **each** psychical page. You can have an Angular app which deals only with the **abc.html** page.

Comment: I actually wanted this, a wizard http://plnkr.co/edit/hblNWZ9UnUhANOz1viF2?p=preview.